# Stack Overflow custom tags don't appear in browser on Android phone

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, custom-filters

When logging into Stack Overflow from Android phone using Chrome browser (may be from any phone using any browser), the custom tag filters and watched tags option does not appear.

Is it possible to add them?

Comment: They’re at the very bottom. Note that [the old mobile views are deprecated](/q/367609/289905).

Comment: @Sebastian Simon I see only the site map links on scrolling down to the bottom, is it possible to post the screenshot to show where to look for the custom watched tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the site header looks black (and rest of the page has a white background with compact elements), you are on the mobile site. Scroll to the bottom and click full site. It looks something like this:

[image]

Then, your filters and such will be towards the middle or bottom of the page, after the list of questions.

Comment: Sorry but the answer is wrong/misleading. I have Stack Overflow in black, and it's not the mobile site. It's a black theme that anyone can choose to have. (The part about switching to full site is correct, but first part of answer is wrong)

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 poor wording on my part. Fixed!